# Tesseract not reading certain numbers

Tags: ruby, ocr, tesseract, minimagick

I started off writing a simple script to read data from an image. Here is my Ruby code that uses RTesseract to read it:

```
require 'rtesseract'
require 'mini_magick'

RTesseract.configure do |config|
    config.processor = "mini_magick"
end

image = RTesseract.new("myImage.jpg")
puts image.to_s
```

I started off with this image:

[image]

The results that came back were: `132B 4`.

I understand that the 0 came back as a B (I can solve that). But the following `3`, `0`, `8` did not return at all. Now I know it already knows how to read a 3 and 0, because it did it in the first number. I figure it had some issues rendering the following numbers, so I made it black and white.

This is the second image I tried:

[image]

However the results still came back as: `132B 4`.

Finally I cut the image and just tried the final 3 numbers.

Here is the image:

[image]

But when I ran the script, it returned no result. Any thoughts on why I am not able to read the final numbers?

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2, rTesseract 2.1.0 and MiniMagick 4.5.1.

I am using Tesseract 3.04.01

Comment: Turn the image into black text on white and remove image compression artifacts, a la @eric-duminil's suggestion.

Anecdotally, for a consistent & known font, I've had better accuracy just doing naive pixel-diff matching per character on my own.

Comment: @Kache: Sounds interesting. Do you have any link?

Comment: @EricDuminil ah, I don't have a link. It was a very naive method: 1. modify & cut up text into normalized black-on-white characters 2. datamine all possible character images & variations that may appear for the font, 3. select character with least pixel-by-pixel differences, using some tricks to not need to count every pixel of every character (e.g. character pixel height/width, num black/white pixels, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your script on my Linux Mint 17 machine, with tesseract 3.03
, Ruby 2.1.5 and MiniMagick 4.5.1

It also returns `132B 4`.

If you're sure that digits are encoded, you could try :

```
image = RTesseract.new("myImage.jpg", options: :digits)
```

It returns `13223 4`.

Launching tesseract without parameter gives you a list of possible options. "pagesegmode 7" looks interesting : `7 = Treat the image as a single text line.`

So :

```
image = RTesseract.new("myImage.jpg", options: :digits, psm: 7)
```

It returns `13223 4 3 21 8`.

With your second image, it returns `3 21 8`.

I think the biggest problem now is that the JPG artifacts are pretty strong and the contrast is relatively low between digits and background. A PNG image would probably yield better results.

With gimp, I resized the image to 200px height, cropped close to the digits to remove some artifacts, used Colors/Threshold at 150, inverted the image and saved as png :

[image]

Rtesseract returns :

```
1320 4 3 0 8
```

With Image Magick, this command achieved the same result :

```
convert myImage.jpg -geometry x200 -threshold 13% -negate myImage.png
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and it almost worked. I am getting 132. 4 3 8. So it still seems to have issues with the zeroes. Any thoughts on why that may be happening?

Comment: (Note: notice it puts a "." for the first 0 and nothing for the second one)

Comment: Could you update Tesseract, or maybe play with the threshold value?

Comment: I will try updating tesseract. I messed with both the geometry settings & the threshold but it didn't seem to work. I also removed negate but that didn't seem to change anything either way.

Comment: Looks like I was up-to-date with Tesseract. The version I had written earlier was rTesseract version. Tesseract currently 3.04.01.

Comment: Got it to work by cutting the image to the numbers and moving the threshold up to 20%. Thank you for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks for the bounty!